# Дамп огромной БД

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Существует MySQL БД, размером 500гб, задача сделать дамп каждой из баз, с наименьшем обращением к серверу. Это необходимо для создания копии на репликаторе. При попытке сделать дам MySqldumpОМ - затыкается вся база... необходимо как то аккуратно сделать дамп чтобы Mysql не сделал mysql server has gone away)

Comment: Может [поможет](http://hashcode.ru/questions/53601/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Не используйте ключик `--opt` (он же дефолтный), потому что он включает блокировку таблиц.

Запускайте так:

```
mysqldump --skip-opt --quick --single-transaction
```

Остальные ключики по вкусу. Конечно, в случае MyISAM таблиц вы можете потерять целостность дампа, например, родительская таблица сдампилась, прошел в нее и в дочернюю `INSERT`, затем дампится дочерняя — и в ней уже есть записи, у которых нет соответствия в родительской.

Ну тут или так, или так. Для InnoDB ситуация лучше, ключик `--single-transaction` спасает.